# potential ARC retain cycle with C++ helper classes?

Tags: c++, objective-c, automatic-ref-counting, objective-c++

I am integrating a C++ library to an iOS app (Objective C) which uses abstract classes to implement an event-handler pattern.

In order to receive the events, I need to implement a C++ class. Unless I'm missing something, I've been implementing C++ classes to implement the abstract interfaces, and then keeping an instance to the Objective-C class, so I can call selectors on it.

Here's an example

```
@implementation MYClass : NSObject
{
    CppHelper * _helper;
}

- (id)init
{
    if(self = [super init])
    {
        _helper = new CppHelper(self);
    }
}

- (void)dealloc
{
    delete _helper;
}

@end
```

...

```
class CppHelper : public AbstractLibraryInterface
{
private:
    MYClass * _parent;
public:
    CppHelper(MYClass * objCParent)
        : _parent(objCParent)
    { }

    onEvent()
    {
        [_parent handleEvent];
    }
};
```

My question is, does passing `self` via the C++ constructor create a strong ARC reference, such that my ObjC classes will be holding onto themselves?

Would using `__bridge void*` and storing the ObjC class as `void*` alleviate this problem? The lifetime of the C++ class is meant to be tied to the parent ObjC class.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, yours self is retained in CppHelper constructor.
I don't love ARC for making simple pointers strong.
You can define `__weak MYClass * _parent;` to avoid retain cycle.

Also why not use abstract interfaces of objective-C: `@protocol` `s?

Comment: normally I would use @protocol, but the library already exists, and I must interface with it